# Multi-key lookup data structure

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, key, lookup

I need an efficient way to look up a user by any 1 of 3 different keys. For example, by *id*, *username* or *alias*.

The basic concept would be a data structure in which you can use any of 3 different types of keys to look up the value:

1. `myDataStructure.lookupByName(name) -> User`
2. `myDataStructure.lookupById(id) -> User`
3. `myDataStructure.lookupByAlias(alias) -> User`

The only immediate way I can think of doing this would be to have *3 separate dictionaries*, and use the one corresponding to the type of key provided.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Three dictionaries is the most efficient way. You could imagine three sorted arrays, sorted by the three different key types, with and shared pointers to the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the keysets (names, ids and aliases) are distinct, you could put them all into a single table. Otherwise, you'd need the three separate tables that you noted.

Comment: I can be sure that each keyset will be distinct however I don't want to be required to provide all 3 to lookup a user.

Comment: If the table is populated beforehand, you shouldn't have to provide all three. Any one of the following could be used to look up the user. myDataStructure.lookupByNameOrIdOrAlias(name) -> USER, myDataStructure.lookupByNameOrIdOrAlias(id) -> USER, myDataStructure.lookupByNameOrIdOrAlias(alias) -> USER

Comment: If you put all three in one dictionary, won't you be stuck with linear-time (i.e., slow) lookup? Using three dictionaries, the lookup would be O(log n) or O(1).

Answer (score 0):

This can also help you. you can extend it to more than one key
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/multikey-dictionary.aspx